# Native spherical (WGS84) coordinates?

Tags: ros, gazebo, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(this is a cross post from answers.gazebosim.com)

I'm looking to build a simulation where I can *accurately* bookkeep my robots position in geodetic coordinates (WGS84 datum).

Unfortunately the ROS+Gazebo+Hector GPS plugin route isn't likely to work, exactly because I'm trying to simulate vehicles at high latitude (near the poles), and traveling large distances *O*(10 km), so the equirectangular projection used by the Hector GPS plugin can't be expected to yield accurate results.

Is it possible to run ROS+Gazebo to run a simulation natively in spherical coordinates? I haven't been able to find any resources to date on this.

If not, have any others found themselves in a similar situation? Outside of writing a dynamical model in MATLAB or similar, have others found an acceptable solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236332/native-spherical-(wgs84)-coordinates?/) by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Spherical Coordinate](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e071428f4891f02ff95188d6089a246d2aa0cc8b/gazebo/common/SphericalCoordinates.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [GPS plugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e071428f4891f02ff95188d6089a246d2aa0cc8b/gazebo/sensors/GpsSensor.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) classes in Gazebo implement WGS84<-->local XYZ coordinates via the intermediate Earth Centered Earth Fixed frame (here's [one](https://microem.ru/files/2012/08/GPS.G1-X-00006.pdf) of many refs on this conversion). This is compared to the equirectangular projection [implemented](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/blob/indigo-devel/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp#L224) by the Hector GPS plugin.

The local XYZ origin is located at the lat/long specified in the Gazebo [world file](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=world#world_spherical_coordinates) and has an ENU (East-North-Up) orientation.

---

Originally posted by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) with karma: 66 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0